# How to get-credential during docker-compose build

Tags: powershell, docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to download some files from a webserver and to do that i need some credentials. I can run the script just fine in powershell:

```
param( 
[String]$sourcefile="",
[String]$destinationfile=""
)

$ftpcred = (Get-Credential)
$ftpUser = $ftpcred.UserName
$ftpPass = $ftpcred.Password

function download
{
    param ([string]$source, [string]$destination)
    $WebClient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
    $webclient.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($ftpUser, $ftpPass)
    $WebClient.DownloadFile("$source","$destination")
}

download $sourcefile $destinationfile
```

But once i run the script during `docker-compose build` from the dockerfile it just halts. I assume that means the `Get-Credential` is running inside the container. I've read you can't run scripts host side during during build by design.

So does anyone have any idea how i get the credentials without storing them in the repo.

Comment: I don't have a full answer for you but you need to create the credential object outside of the container and read it in inside the container. https://www.pdq.com/blog/secure-password-with-powershell-encrypting-credentials-part-1 goes over some good techniques for doing this. There is also a part two as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved this by running the script pre-build and copying over the file it downloaded to the container.